# you don't have permission to access [custom alias] on this server

Tags: wamp, wampserver

can anyone help with a following issue:
I am using wamp to run projects in my chrome browser.
after adding a newAlias which points to my project directory c:/dev/myProject
I am getting Forbidden message: you don't have permission to access /newAlias on this server.
I can access default Aliases such as phpmyadmin, webgrind...
but i cannot access my own. 
I am using WampServer Version 2.5 64bit on Win 8.1 64bit located in c:/wamp.
I tried basic stuff from the net but with no luck. 
Any suggestions?

Edit: content of newAlias:

```
Alias /bs1/ "c:/_DEV_/git/NewProject/www/" 

<Directory "c:/_DEV_/git/NewProject/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: So show the contents of the `\wamp\alias\newalias.conf`. Edit the question, dont put it in a comment

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dont change that section of your `httpd.conf`. Those few lines control access to the root folder of the drive that Apache is installed on. So you just gave full access to anybody with a handy hack.

The process of securing the access via Apache is to deny all access to everything from the root folder and below, and then **selectively** allow access for specific sites to specific areas/folders of the drive.

A better solution would be to change `httpd.conf` back to how it was and make the change in your Alias definition. Like this :-

```
Alias /bs1 "c:/_DEV_/git/NewProject/www/" 

<Directory "c:/_DEV_/git/NewProject/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require local          # <-- to develop on this PC
    Require ip 192.168.1   # <-- to access server from another PC on your network
    Require all granted    # <-- to allow the world to see the beauty of your site
</Directory>
```

It is actually a better idea to use Virtual Hosts to control each site and not Alias's.

Here is a why and Howto :- [WAMPServer 2.5 The Homepage, Your Projects Menu and the need for Virtual Hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: Multiple `Require` directives paradoxically are the way to allow multiple networks.

Answer (score 12):

I've updated WAMP from 2.2.22 to 2.4.9 and found that new aliases didn't work (same error message as yours).

Checking the default aliases like phpmyadmin, I've found this:

```bash
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

If you see the contents of the file you'll notice the `<IfDefine APACHE24>` and `<IfDefine !APACHE24>` conditionals. So I've changed my alias .conf file **from:**

```bash
Alias /svn "c:/work/website-svn/" 

<Directory "c:/work/website-svn/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

**to:**

```bash
Alias /svn "c:/work/website-svn/" 

<Directory "c:/work/website-svn/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    Require local

</Directory>
```

That solved my problem, I hope it solves yours.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. WAMP 2.5 comes with Apache 2.4, which uses `Require` for access control. Apache 2.2 used the `Order, Deny, Allow, Satisfy` directives. See here for upgrading from Apache 2.2 to 2.4: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html.

Comment: Shouldn't WAMP take that change into account when it adds an alias? By deafult it uses the old syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on this but the answer above seemed like I was granting access to my entire computer...So tried modifying the above answer to only giving access to where my alias folder is...

So instead...Go to the httpd.conf file...and do a search for...

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

and below that add the following

```
<Directory "c:/path-to-your-alias-folder...">
   AllowOverride none
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This worked to me and I think it might be a bit safer...Again I am no expert here...Just trying to make it work...

Answer (score 1):

for allow permission for your server & wamp you require 3 steps please ensure these 3 things after that you can access your site from other network with ip address e.g http://192.168.1.1/yoursitefoldername
(192.168.1.1 is you computer or vps ip address "yoursitefoldername" is folder name of your site which should be in your wamp->www folder)

**1.**

first of all
Port 80 and 443 must be allow for both TCP and UDP packets. To do this, create 2 inbound rules for TPC and UDP on Windows Firewall for port 80 and 443.
(or you can disable your whole firewall for testing but permanent solution if allow inbound rule)

**2.**

#### If you are using WAMPServer 3 See bottom of answer

#### For WAMPServer versions <= 2.5

You need to change the security setting on Apache to allow access from anywhere else, so edit your `httpd.conf` file.

Change this section from :

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
```

To :

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
```

if "Allow from all" line not work for your then use "Require all granted"
then it will work for you.

#### WAMPServer 3 has a different method

In version 3 and > of WAMPServer there is a Virtual Hosts pre defined for `localhost` so dont amend the `httpd.conf` file at all, leave it as you found it.

Using the menus, edit the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

[image]

It should look like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Amend it to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot D:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "D:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hopefully you will have created a Virtual Host for your project and not be using the `wamp\www` folder for your site. In that case leave the localhost definition alone and make the change only to your Virtual Host.

**3.**
**Dont forget to restart All Services of Wamp or Apache after making this change**

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which worked for me. 
In httpd.conf i changed:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Which solved the issue and allowed me to access my custom aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you consider setting up virtual hosts instead.  It takes a few more minutes, but it's more bulletproof.  RiggsFolly's answer to a similar question is excellent in its detail, rigor, and utility:

[Project Links do not work on Wamp Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)